# Windows Service: Specified eventSource exists already

Tags: c#, windows-services, event-log

I'm writing a Windows Service in C# (.NET 4).

Here is the code for the installer:

```
 [RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class JobManagerInstaller : Installer
{
    public JobManagerInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Installers.Clear();

        ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
        EventLogInstaller eventLogInstaller = new EventLogInstaller();

        // Service Account Information
        serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
        serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;

        // Service Information
        // The installer's ServiceName must be identical to the JobManager.ServiceName set in the constructor of JobManager.cs
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "VIAVista";
        serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "VIAVista";
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

        // EventLog
        eventLogInstaller.Source = "VIAVista";
        eventLogInstaller.Log = "VIAVista";

        // Dependency SQL Server service (i.e.SQL Server must run)
        serviceInstaller.ServicesDependedOn = new string[] { "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS" };

        this.Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
        this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        this.Installers.Add(eventLogInstaller);
    }
}
```

As you can see I want my event's source and log to be named "VIAVista".

When I try to install the service on my server (Windows Web Server 2008 R2 64bit) I'm told that the event source already exists in log "Application". That's weird since I thought this.Installers.Clear() would prevent creating a default source/log.

Info: I used regedit to make sure that there is no "VIAVista" key before installing the service.

Any ideas? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
     serviceInstaller.Installers.Clear();
```

Comment: Is this different from this.Installers.Clear() ?

Comment: Ok, so I replaced my this.Installers.Clear() with your serviceInstaller.Installers.Clear(). I can now install my service. A new key has been created in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\eventlog\VIAVista

Comment: This is what I expected. However, when I open the EventViewer console, all my service events are written to the Application log (having source==VIAVista). I was hoping for a separate node in the log tree.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))
    EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log);

EventLog.WriteEntry(source, message, type, eventid);
```

If the source exists it will be used, otherwise it will be created.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for your help. Actually this was my first approach. But this failed (maybe due to permission issues). That's why I wanted to create the log during the installation.